# MySQL Query for Summing Values per Week

Tags: c#, mysql, date, select

I have a table in my Database named `tblSales`. It has two columns, `Date` and `Sales`. `Date` is the primary key, and `Sales` would be the amount of sales for the given date.
Suppose my table contains the following values:

```
**************************
*    Date    *   Sales   *
**************************
* 2013-12-31 *    150.00 *
* 2014-01-01 *     50.00 *
* 2014-01-02 *    100.00 *
* 2014-01-03 *     25.00 *
* 2014-01-08 *    200.00 *
* 2014-01-10 *     50.00 *
* 2014-01-16 *     25.00 *
* 2014-01-29 *    500.00 *
**************************
```

I want to get the sum of the values per week based on:
a) each week of the year
b) each week starting with a specified date

As for REQUIREMENT A, the starting date would be based on the starting date of the first week of the year. For example, in the year 2014, the first week starts with December 30 up until January 5. I would have an output like this:

```
**************************
*    Date    *   Sales   *
**************************
* 2013-12-30 *    325.00 * <--- Week 1 of the year 2014 (Dec. 30 - Jan. 05)
* 2014-01-06 *    250.00 * <--- Week 2 of the year 2014 (Jan. 06 - Jan. 12)
* 2014-01-13 *     25.00 * <--- Week 3 of the year 2014 (Jan. 13 - Jan. 19)
* 2014-01-20 *      0.00 * <--- Week 4 of the year 2014 (Jan. 20 - Jan. 26)
* 2014-01-27 *    500.00 * <--- Week 5 of the year 2014 (Jan. 27 - Feb. 02)
**************************
```

As for REQUIREMENT B, the starting date would have to be specified. For example, I specified that the date would start at Jan. 02, 2014. I would get the following result:

```
**************************
*    Date    *   Sales   *
**************************
* 2014-01-02 *    325.00 * <--- Week dates: Jan. 02 - Jan. 08
* 2014-01-09 *     50.00 * <--- Week dates: Jan. 09 - Jan. 15
* 2014-01-16 *     25.00 * <--- Week dates: Jan. 16 - Jan. 22
* 2014-01-23 *    500.00 * <--- Week dates: Jan. 23 - Jan. 29
**************************
```

The dates in the date column after the SELECT command would be the starting dates for each week.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `WEEK()` function to GROUP BY WEEK.

Build something like this:

```
SELECT WEEK(Date) AS WEEK DATES,
       SUM(Sales)
...
GROUP BY WEEK(Date)
....
```

Can also do something like this to show the dates `CONCAT(date, '-', date + INTERVAL 6 DAY)`

Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my desired results using:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(Date, 0), ' ', 'Sunday'), '%X%V %W') AS 'Week Start', 
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(Date, 0), ' ', 'Saturday'), '%X%V %W') AS 'Week End',
       SUM(Sales) AS Sales 
FROM tblSales
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(Date)
ORDER BY YEARWEEK(Date);
```

And it would display something like this:

[image: Sample result using the query above]

Another way would be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(Date, 0), ' ', 'Sunday'), '%X%V %W'), 
              ' - ', 
              STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(Date, 0), ' ', 'Saturday'), '%X%V %W')
             ) AS Week, 
       SUM(Sales) AS Sales 
FROM tblSales
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(Date, 0)
ORDER BY YEARWEEK(Date, 0);
```

And it would display something like this:

[image: Sample result using the query above]

I do appreciate Arun's answer, however, to make sure same week numbers from different years don't sum up together, use the `YEARWEEK`. Note that in my queries, the week starts with Sunday.